# Having Google's multiple sign-in log in to the same accounts

Tags: google-workspace, google-account, google-multi-login

Since Google Apps accounts and Google Accounts have combined, I can now sign into both accounts but their relationship only lives until the end of the session or I logout.

I log back in I have to sign into the first account and into the second account again since they don't maintain that relationship beyond the session. Is there anyway to permanently associate the accounts so that when I log into one account, it automatically logs into both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not because:
Although Google Apps and Google Accounts allow you to access several of the same Google products, they're different types of accounts. A Google Account is a unified sign-in system that provides access to a variety of free Google consumer products -- such as Gmail, Google Groups, Google Shopping List, Picasa, Web History, iGoogle, and Google Checkout -- administered by Google. Google Apps provides access to products powered by Google but administered by a your organization.

What you can access directly from a google account are things such as Documents, Google Reader, Google calendar, etc. (all that appears near the upper left side of your screen when you log into google, including the utilities in the drop down menu.

Comment: Thanks @Mariana. I had hoped to save some time, but I can enter in the passwords for now and hope it changes sometime in the future.